# find the ip address on Linksys

Tags: ip, router, linksys

I get two differents Linksys routers : WAG54GX2 and WAP54G.

I tried to get the IP address to reset the routers correctly and verify if they are still working. So I use the RJ45 cable on my routers and linked them to my computer.

Then, I tried the default address : 192.168.1.1, I get nothing...

So I tried the cmd `ipconfig/all`,  I get :

```
Configuration IP de Windows

   Nom de l’hôte . . . . . . . . . . : DESKTOP
   Suffixe DNS principal . . . . . . :
   Type de noeud. . . . . . . . . .  : Hybride
   Routage IP activé . . . . . . . . : Non
   Proxy WINS activé . . . . . . . . : Non

Carte réseau sans fil Connexion au réseau local* 1 :

   Statut du média. . . . . . . . . . . . : Média déconnecté
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Adresse physique . . . . . . . . . . . : DC-41-A9-A3-DC-C6
   DHCP activé. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Oui
   Configuration automatique activée. . . : Oui

Carte réseau sans fil Connexion au réseau local* 2 :

   Statut du média. . . . . . . . . . . . : Média déconnecté
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
   Adresse physique . . . . . . . . . . . : DE-41-A9-A3-DC-C5
   DHCP activé. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Oui
   Configuration automatique activée. . . : Oui

Carte Ethernet Ethernet 2 :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek USB GbE Family Controller #2
   Adresse physique . . . . . . . . . . . : 74-78-27-8C-49-9B
   DHCP activé. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Oui
   Configuration automatique activée. . . : Oui
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::3026:3c69:7d6c:b483%17(préféré)
   Adresse d’autoconfiguration IPv4 . . . : 169.254.180.131(préféré)
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   **Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . :**
   IAID DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . : 309622823
   DUID de client DHCPv6. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-27-40-03-E4-0C-37-96-0C-11-3A
   Serveurs DNS. . .  . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS sur Tcpip. . . . . . . . . . . : Activé
```

Based on what I saw : https://www.linksys.com/fr/support-article?articleNum=132891 , default gateway should not be empty... In my case it's empty.

Do you guys can tell me what is my trouble on this 2 routers?

EDIT, add screen shots for comment :
[image]

Thanks

Comment: DHCP is not running/working on the routers.  The address 169.254.x.x indicates that your computer did not get an address from the DHCP server in the router.

Comment: @RonTrunk thanks. I checked : https://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=135673 
Seems like on step one, I have to do : https://www.linksys.com/us/support-article/?articleNum=140973 : `Enter your router’s default IP address, "192.168.1.1", or type "myrouter.local" in the Address bar then press [Enter].| ` -> and this is not working for me...

Comment: try setting your IP address manually to 192.168.1.2 (255.255.255.0) and see if you can connect.  If not, there is something wrong with your router or cable,

Comment: @RonTrunk how can I set the IP manually? thanks

Comment: Set the IP address on your computer.  Use the Control panel

Comment: @RonTrunk, I tried, I edited the post, did I do it correctly? If yes, then it's not working and I changed my cable. Thanks

Comment: That is correct.  Be sure to change it back to "Obtenir une adrese IP automatiquement."

Comment: Yes, thanks ! So my router is not working anymore for sure?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Based on the comments before : That's because they are not working anymore..

Comment: I'm new, why are you downvote that? I closed the case because of the @RonTrunk comments